# java retrieve original element from object

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to java and what I'm currently trying is.

For example I have 2 classes 1 for Employees which can have a name number and email and one for Vehicles which have number type and status.

I retrieve data from an API for both classes and fill and `ArrayList<Employee>` and `ArrayList<Vehicle>` with all the data.

Both of these classes need to go through the same function which will create an excel file based on the data.

The problem I'm facing currently is that I want to use both of these arraylist in my function but based on which one I get to do other things inside the function and for this I need to know which arraylist was forwarded to the function. What I'm trying to do is following:

I have a function

```
Public static void createExcel(Object[] obj){ //do something }
```

I give the function the type Object so that I can get both of the arraylists. So I parsed the Arraylists as followed:

```
ArrayLists<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
employees.add(employee);
Object[] objArray = employees.toArray();
ExcelWriter.createExcel(objArray);
```

The same for Vehicle.
Now my question is how can I in the createExcel funtion retrieve which arraylist was passed and how can I get my original arraylist from this object array? or is this not possible and do I have to do it another way?

EDIT:

To make it a bit more clear I would like my excel function to be something like this:

```
if(obj == type of ArrayLists<Employee>()){ //retrieve my original employees arraylist here }
```

And the same for Vehicle

Comment: This is a very broad question with a lot of possible solutions involving for instance generics or applying a custom interface but if you are a beginner I think you should start with having 2 createExcel methods, one for each type of ArrayList. When you have that working you can start looking at refactoring your design and trying to remove duplicate code. Start simple and go from there rather than aiming for something very advanced from the start

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I edited my answer (maybe it narrows it a bit down) and yes I did this and that is why I'm now trying to make it better cause now I have 20times the excel function which is horrific to watch :p

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean with “20times the excel function” but looking at your edit I don’t think trying to determine the type of the objects/list is the way to go, you want to be able to use the same code for both type of objects

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I mean at the moment I have 20 classes that all need to be made in excels, so at the moment I have my createExcel function 20 times for each of my classes. and yes that was indeed what I was trying to do sorry my English is not that good and it is hard to correctly phrase what I'm trying to do...

Comment: This means in the accepted answer below you need 20 if/else which will be horrible. Maybe it’s time for you to learn about Interfaces so you can create one for all of your 20 classes to implement and the the createExcel method could take an array or ArrayList of that Interface so you only needed to handle that single type

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ok you are completely correct at what you say, I will start looking into interfaces and try to do it your way cause it sounds indeed much better than what I was going to do now, thank you very much!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ok so I did some research towards interfaces. So I will have to create 20 interfaces for my classes which each have their createExcel method? Is this so much better to have 20 interfaces with a createExcel method then just having 20 if's?

Comment: You create 1 interface and let all classes implement it

Comment: Ahh I see, I can create 1 interface with the createExcel method and implement it in all classes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the actual type of an object using `instanceof`:

```
public static void createExcel(Object[] obj){ 
    // Assume array is not empty
    Object o = obj[0];
    if ( o instanceof Employee ) {
         // It's an Employee
    }
    else if ( o instanceof Vehicule ) {
         // It's a Vehicule
    }
    else {
         // Should probably throw an Exception here
    }
}
```

But if you wish to do different things dependening on the type of the parameter, why would you write a single function?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear the main functionality of the function is all the same I edited my question. The only thing that I want in the beginning of my function is as you suggest here with the instanceof to be also able to retrieve my original Arraylist of either Employee or Vehicle. so if you could also tell me how I could get my original employees arraylist from my Object[] obj then I think this would solve my problem :).

Comment: never mind I am stupid, I forgot to take the [0] of obj to get my array. Thank you very much this works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Override createExcel [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

```java
public static void createExcel(List<Employee> employees){
    ...
    ExcelWriter.createExcel(employees.toArray());
    ...
}

public static void createExcel(List<Vehicle> vehicles){ 
    ...
    ExcelWriter.createExcel(vehicles.toArray());
    ...
}
```